# How to create a context menu before Eclipse Import menu item in Eclipse Plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, eclipse-pde

I want to add a new menu just before Eclipse `Import...` menu. I am able to create a context menu item, but I want to place it before `Import...`. I provide below the code snippet from `plugin.xml`.

```
<menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
         <menu
               icon="icons/someIcon.png"
               id="com.sample.app.sampleMenu"
               label="PathXplorer">
            <command
                  commandId="com.sample.app.commands.actionid"
                  icon="icons/someIcon.png"
                  id="ccom.sample.app.menus.action1Id"
                  label="Some Good Label">
            </command>
        </menu>
</menuContribution>
```

For more clarity, you can see below the image. My menu will be `Sample Action Menu` which should be visible before import. Please help me to resolve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id of the Import menu item seems to be `import` so your can specify you menu contribution position using the relative position in the `locationURI`:

```xml
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?before=import">
```